# How to Unicode String Convert to another type of Unicode String

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, pattern-matching

I want to replace a Unicode string with a different type when it comes to a specific type of Unicode string in the string.

EX) 1.

```
//Hexadecimal 4characters
string base="U+1234FFFF040001041234";
//I want to replace this type----> &#x1234;&#xFFFF;&#x0400;&#x0104;&#x1234;
```

EX) 2.

```
//Hexadecimal 4characters
string base="U+1234 U+FFFF U+0400 U+0104 U+1234";
//----> &#x1234; &#xFFFF; &#x0400; &#x0104; &#x1234;
```

I am wondering how to do pattern matching with regular expressions.
And I wonder how I can replace it in such a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Regex regexUnicode = new Regex(@"U\+([0-9A-F]{4})+");

        MatchCollection resultCollection = regexUnicode.Matches(str);
        foreach (Match matched in resultCollection) {

            int length = matched.Groups[0].Length;                      
            string matchedStr = matched.Groups[0].ToString();           
            int startIndex = str.IndexOf(matchedStr);                   
            string temp = matchedStr;
            string ret = "";
            string buffer = "";
            int bufCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < matchedStr.Length; ++i) {
                if (matchedStr[i] == 'U' || matchedStr[i] == '+') {
                    continue;
                } else if (bufCount != 4) {                         
                    buffer += matchedStr[i];
                    bufCount++;
                } else if (bufCount == 4) {                          
                    ret += "&#x" + buffer + ";";
                    buffer = "";
                    buffer += matchedStr[i];
                    bufCount = 1;
                }
            }
            ret += "&#x" + buffer + ";";
            str = str.Remove(startIndex, matchedStr.Length);       
            str = str.Insert(startIndex, ret);                     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C# (I use Java mostly), but here's an abstract description of what I would do:

EX) 1.
 - Turn the string into a character array

- Create an empty string (String s = "")
- Create a loop that adds the prefix, plus the next four characters (in loop: s = s + "&#x" + charArray[k] + charArray[k+1] + charArray[k+2] + charArray[k+3])
- Add the semicolon at the end

EX) 2.

- the pattern you'll want to match which will be replaced is: " U\+", and you'll be replacing that with "; &#x". But you will have to take the first U+ off beforehand.

The reason why you have to add a backslash before the plus is because that is the repetition operator, and the backslash will escape it. I don't know about C#, but in Java, you have to escape the escape in a string, so you would actually use " U\\+"